# Can I clear browser cache of the page leaving page?

Tags: html

Can I clear browser cache of the page when I'm leaving it.

```
// Clear browser cache
Response.Redirect("otherpage.html");
```

By "clean browser cache" I didn't mean all the cache. I meant make user download the page next time he goes back to it (by pressing back button in my case).

**Edit**
Usually Sky Sanders suggestion works. In fact that what I tried right away, but even though it worked for simple page it failed when putting Response.Redirect after cache headers. Even though FF received headers it still provided me with a cached page when I pressed back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can control caching from the content end of the stick is to prevent caching in the first place.

```
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

You cannot invoke methods on the client browser.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't clear the browser cache from your web app. You could clear the cookies but that's about it.